# initialise view from NIB

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, interface-builder

I am trying to initialise a view from a NIB file onto my view controller on Storyboard.

Here is what I did:

1. drag a view controller onto storyboard, placed a UIView obj as a placeholder view and change its class to my custom view class named "CustomControl".
2. next I setup CustomControl class from a NIB file, connect outlets of its subviews and so on.

my question is how to load this CustomControl view from nib to the placeholder view that I have on my view controller? The reason I want to do this separately with a nib file is because I might want to reuse this control (custom UIView class) with other projects, and also I think it would be easier if I could just setup view constraints between the view controller and the placeholder view without worry too much of the control's constraint respect to the view controller.

thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks guys for your answers, and sorry about my wording. I am not having trouble with loading view controllers, but instead, loading a custom view (from nib file) onto my view controller (on storyboard, which have a plain UIView as placeholder view for the nib). So when the view controller is loaded, the plain placeholder view becomes that nib file I created

Answer (score 0):

Leave this off the Storyboard all together.

Instead of having a placeholder, have nothing. When another controller wants to load this view controller, it can use `[[MyViewController alloc] init]` or `[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil]`. After the view controller is created, then it can push it on the navigation controller, assign it to a tab, or pop it up as a presented view controller.

You lose the ability to do segues, but you don't actually need them.

Answer (score 0):

Have a wrapper view controller.

Instead of placing your non-storyboard view controller in the storyboard, place a wrapper view controller in the storyboard.

The wrapper view controller instantiates the non-storyboard view controller. The wrapper then adds the non-storyboard as a child view controller (`-addChildViewController:`). Finally the wrapper's view add the non-storyboard's view as a subview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    …
    MyViewController *child = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:child];
    [self.view addSubview:child.view];
    …
}
```